# copy & rename files to other folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have some of log files formatted like this `"name.log"`

I would like to copy those from one folder to another folder like

```
xcopy  /y  "C:\Folder1" "D:\Folder2"
```

And i need to rename file with created date of original file (no copy file) so that the text file in Folder2 would be like `"name yyyymmddhhmm.log"` if some file has the same name (date of creation) it will be overwritten.

The code:

```
set Source=C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Folder1
set Dest=D:\Folder2
if not exist %Dest% md %Dest%
for /F %%a in ('dir /b "%Source%\*.txt"') do call :Sub %%a
goto :eof

:Sub
set "filename=%1"
for /F %%s in ("%Source%\%1") do  if %%~zs==0 goto :eof
set "datepart="
FOR /F "tokens=1-5 delims=/-: " %%a IN ('dir /tc "%filename%" ^| findstr "%filename%"') DO (
    IF "%%c" neq "" SET "datepart=%%c%%a%%b%%d%%e"
)
FOR /F %%a IN ("%filename%") DO (
    set "NewName=%%~na %datepart%%%~xa"
)
xcopy /y "%Source%\%filename%" "%Dest%\%NewName%*"
GOTO :EOF
```

The problem is that If I don't put the .bat in the same folder that origin files (Folder1),the files aren't change name. For example, if it is out, the files change name with old name and one white space.

The command windows tell me that it doesn't find the file when it get the creation date.

If I put the script into folder1 it works well.

On the other hand, if I execute the script with "Task Scheduler" I have the same problem. The files are copied but without date of creation.

What do I need to solve this problem?

Comment: It's probably due to permissions. Make sure the folder is writable by the user.

Comment: Hello, I've just tested in two folders on my desktop and the operation is the same, thank you

Comment: The new name is `name yyyymmddhhmm.log` (according to your code) rather than `yyyymmddhhmm.log` (according to the description), so please clarify; anyway, the problem is caused by the `dir /tc "%filename%"` command, which should be changed to `dir /tc "%Source%\%filename%"`; in addition, the `findstr` command line should be changed to `findstr /L /E /C:"%filename%"` to (at least almost) match the entire file name; finally, the `FOR /F %%a` part should be changed to `FOR "eol=| delims=" %%a`...

Comment: Hello, Sorry I've just edited, the correct option is name yyyymmddhhmm.log  
I get this error: It was not expected "eol=| delims=" after change you said me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

set Source=C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Folder1
set Dest=D:\Folder2

set "Source=u:\sourcedir\t w o"
set "Dest=u:\destdir"

if not exist "%Dest%" md "%Dest%"

for /F "delims=" %%k in ('dir /b "%Source%\*.log"') do call :Sub "%%k"
goto :eof

:Sub
SET "newname=%~1"

for /F "delims=" %%s in ("%Source%\%~1") do (if %%~zs==0 goto :eof

 FOR /F "tokens=1-5 delims=/-: " %%a IN ('dir /tc "%Source%\%~1" ^| findstr "%~1"') DO (
    IF "%%c" neq "" SET "newname=%%~ns %%c%%a%%b%%d%%e%%~xs"
 )
)
ECHO(xcopy /y "%Source%\%~1" "%Dest%\%NewName%"
GOTO :EOF
```

The required XCOPY commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(XCOPY` to `XCOPY` to actually copy the files. Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file copied`)

This may seem quite a radical change, but actually it really isn't.

First issue is that I overrode your directory settings with directories to suit my system. The syntax `SET "var=value"` (where value may be empty) is used to ensure that any stray trailing spaces are NOT included in the value assigned. `set /a` can safely be used "quoteless".

Using quotes in the `md` command makes the procedure immune to `"paths containing separators"` - I test using spaces in paths and filenames because that appears to be a popular thing to do.

I changed the directory-scan metavariable from `%%a` to `%%k` to avoid confusion with the `%%a` in the subroutine. Your text says that you are starting with `&.log` files, but your filemask was `*.txt` so I changed it to `*.log`. Quoting the parameter delivered to `:Sub` means the procedure will receive the entire name of the file if it contains spaces.

Within the subroutine, it would appear that yowant no name-change if the `%%c` part from the `dir/tc` scan is empty. `%~1` is the supplied filename minus the quotes.

The outer loop in `%%s` : I added `delims=` to cater for spaces in filenames and used `%~1` in preference to `%filename%`

Within the `%%s` block, `%%s` refers to the file, so you can use `%%s` and its modified forms like `%%~zs` to refer to that file's characteristics - which unfortunately do not include create-date (`%%~ts` contains the last-update date - you may be able to use that in te following line rather than `dir` and `findstr`)

Then as @aschipfi suggested, include the source directory in the `dir` otherwise the `dir` takes place on the **current** directory.

```
 FOR /F "tokens=1-5 delims=/-: " %%a IN ("%%~ts") DO (
```

should work for you if you can use last-update-date in place of create-date.

So - if `%%c` is not empty, set the new name to (the name part of the file in `%%s`)+space+the date string+(the extension in `%%s`)

And then do the `xcopy` - using the old name unless it was modified.

Comment: I'm sorry, I checked with .txt files and I didn't remember to change it. Thank you very much for your explaination so clearly. I have one doub, why do you use "t w o" in "sourcedir\t w o" line?

Comment: In order to check that it works with a directoryname that contains spaces - I put testfiles into that directory (it's on a RAMdrive, so it neatly gets deleted at power-off) - both the test files and the directory name contain spaces, so if it works, it'll also work for a file/directoryname not containing spaces (within reason - if you want to use awkward symbols to which `cmd` assigns special meaning like `&` - then you get to solve the consequent problems.)